# Inner join the tables where the value of one column is different. But the meaning of the values are same

Tags: sql

Table t1

[image: Table t1]

Table t2

[image: Table t2]

I tried running the query

```
select CountyCode, ContactPerson
  from table1  t1
    inner join select * from table 2 t2 on t1.CountyCode[1] = Code[0]
```

Any one help me please.

Comment: What is `[1]` and [0]` supposed to be?

Comment: Is `CountyCode` an array? Or what do you expect `CountyCode[1]` to do?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? `inner join select * ... on ...` is invalid SQL (regardless of the intention behind using the array subscript `[..]`)

Comment: I want to join the tables. I tried to split the characters of the values in the column. I thought the second character matches the first character. but threw error. I don't know how to join them. If the values are same means I would have used inner join on = column names. I appreciate any help please. Countycode(LAPN) is called as ALP in another table.

Comment: @BaleshD How does `LAPN` equal to `ALP`? You'll need some sort of table to match this.

Comment: @LVB: Like UnitesStates in one table and US in another table. I dont have another common column where I can apply join. The only criteria I have to map is based on the UnitedStates = US. This is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
select CountyCode, ContactPerson
  from t1
    inner join t2 on t1.CountyCode = t2.Code
```

Comment: I tried it but I got 0 records because no data is matched right.

Comment: Well, the elements of the two tables must be related. In one the main key and in the other the external key